# Switching from class component to functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math, react-hooks

So I have code here that is supposed to calculate a price based off of property sqft and the package selected.

The code used to work with class components when I had it written like so... but Im now using react JS and Functional components.

The current issue I am having right now is getting the `setBasePrice(1234);` to actually set the base price so it can be calculated in the function.

Im also having an issue with getting the `basePrice += basePrice * (percentage / 100);` to work properly in the functional component.

I know I have this totally wrong right now just hoping someone can point me in the right direction and possibly show me how to clean up my code.

**UPDATED**

I added the useEffect hook and the total price is coming up incorrectly. at 5500 sqft the price should be $272 but comes up as $112. My old code doesnt do this so im not sure whats going on.

**Class Component**

```
 this.state = {
      propertySqft: "",
      packageSelected: this.props.location.state,
      totalPrice: null,
      basePrice: null
    };
  }

  checkPrice = () => { 
      debugger;
       if(this.state.packageSelected === "Photography"){
        this.state.basePrice = 159.998;
       }else if(this.state.packageSelected === "Video"){
            this.state.basePrice = 416.998;
       }else if(this.state.packageSelected === "Drone Aerial Photos Only"){
            this.state.basePrice = 199.998;
       }else if(this.state.packageSelected === "Drone Aerial Video Only"){
            this.state.basePrice = 249.998;
       }else if(this.state.packageSelected === "Drone Aerials Photo & Video"){
            this.state.basePrice = 299.998;
       }else if(this.state.packageSelected === "Photography, Video, Drone Aerials"){
            this.state.basePrice = 559.998;
       }if(this.state.propertySqft > 2500){
   let overage = this.state.propertySqft - 2000;
   let percentage = Math.floor(overage / 500) * 10;
   this.state.basePrice += this.state.basePrice * (percentage / 100);


  }
     this.setState({ totalPrice: Math.round(this.state.basePrice * 100) / 100 }); 
  }
```

**Functional Component**

```
const [basePrice, setBasePrice] = useState(0);
const [newPrice, setNewPrice] = useState(null);
const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  setTotalPrice(basePrice => (Math.round(basePrice * 100) / 100));
}, [basePrice]); 

const checkPrice = () => { 
      debugger;
       if(packageSelected.packages === "Photography"){
         setBasePrice(159.998);
       }else if(packageSelected.packages === "Video"){
         setBasePrice(516.998);
       }else if(packageSelected.packages === "Drone Aerial Photos Only"){
         setBasePrice(119.998);
       }else if(packageSelected.packages === "Drone Aerial Video Only"){
         setBasePrice(269.998);
       }else if(packageSelected.packages === "Drone Aerials Photo & Video"){
         setBasePrice(549.998);
       }else if(packageSelected.packages === "Photography, Video, Drone Aerials"){
         setBasePrice(566.998);   
       }if(propertySqft > 2000){
   const overage = propertySqft - 2000;
   const percentage = Math.floor(overage / 500) * 10;
    setBasePrice(basePrice => (basePrice * (percentage / 100)));
 }
  };
```

Comment: what errors are showing? can you add that so we can see?

Comment: Why dont you initialize you prices with `0` instead of `null`, that way the type will always be `number` and it can never fail.

Comment: Im actually not getting any errors, its just that when i call setBasePrice(339.998); it doesnt set the basePrice

Comment: There's really no need to have a state in this component. I don't understand why you'd want to change a working component only to use hooks?

Comment: Also, the reason it doesn't work is because you were misusing the state in the class component to begin with. `this.state.basePrice = 249.998;` mutates the state and is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: @oemera When I initialize with 0 it stays 0 the whole time for some reason. the setBasePrice is completely ignored it seems like.

Comment: [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997/1218980)

Comment: @Emile Bergeron It's always better to migrate to the recommended way and keep your code consistent.

Comment: @oemera Class components aren't deprecated, there's no reason to migrate. Hooks are solving a really specific issue with shared behaviour composition in huge applications, otherwise completely unnecessary.

Comment: I think he's now learning React hooks and just wants to know how a class component would directly translate to a functional component

Comment: @mph85 I agree that learning is the only other situation where it would make sense to translate a class component to a function component with hooks.

Comment: I never said it's deprecated. Dan Abramov recommended to use functional components with hooks and use hooks in existing project, when you create new components. Considering that, my main point was to keep the code consistent.You don't have to migrate, I just think it's better if you have the time.

Comment: @oemera _"We recommend avoiding any “big rewrites”, especially for existing, complex class components."_ directly taken from the [documentation on hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#gradual-adoption-strategy).

Comment: The same paragraph implies that it would be good to migrate, but that you shouldn't do right away => "There is no rush to migrate to hooks." Otherwise migrating wouldn't even be mentioned. "we will keep supporting class components for the foreseeable future" => Main focus will be hooks.

Comment: @oemera you're incorrectly implying things. They mention that there's no rush to migrate since it's not meant as a replacement to class components and then they ensure that class components will be kept and they're not planning to deprecate them. They wrote this explicitly to avoid the confusion that everyone should use hooks and that class components shouldn't be used. Hooks are definitely clean and improve reusability.

Comment: I think we both at least agree that this is not the right place to discuss this any further :) I see your point, tho

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203203/discussion-between-oemera-and-emile-bergeron).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. When you want to set the base price depending on the value of base price earlier, you can use the callback version of `setBasePrice` function:

```
setBasePrice(basePrice => (basePrice + (basePrice * (percentage / 100)));
```

This way you know that `basePrice` value would be calculated from the latest.

[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

2. From what I understand, you need to calculate total amount whenever the base price changes. Instead of calculating this everywhere `basePrice` changes, you can add this to a `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTotalPrice(Math.round(basePrice * 100) / 100);
}, [basePrice]);
```

In your current code, because `setBasePrice` is async, it will not have completed execution when `setTotalPrice` runs and hence will be a step behind. 
Here, `basePrice` is added as a dependency to `useEffect` and it will be updated once `basePrice` changes.

PS: Your class component is also setting a value directly to state which is wrong, it should be using a `setState` to perform that update.

Comment: @Agney, great answer! Just a quick question. Do you think to use a callback to setState within useEffect is the simplest way to handle component wide async states?

Comment: yes, that would be the declarative way to go about it

Comment: So for some reason the base price still comes up as 0 or undefined. Im not sure what im doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure `checkPrice` is getting called? If so, you might update your post with the corresponding code including the suggested changes from @Agney

Comment: Yes it is getting called and I just updated thanks for reminding me! The price is coming up as the wrong price now just need to figure out why.

Comment: I wonder if the  += has anything to do with why it isnt working properly.

Comment: You are right @Agney 's code doesn't replicate the functionality 100%. It has to be `setBasePrice(basePrice => {return basePrice + (basePrice * (percentage / 100)})`

Comment: @oemera Good catch, hadn't noted the `+=`